# ¿Cómo usar el método chunk para hacer paginación?

Tags: laravel, paginación

Tengo un controller en donde mando a llamar

```
$events = Eventos::all();
```

lo mando a través de `$data` a una vista que tengo y luego con un `foreach`, lo itero en una tabla para mostrar ciertos datos, pero estoy teniendo problemas porque una de las tablas tiene arriba de 50,000 registros entonces mi navegador se congela.

Me dijeron que el método `chunk` puede ayudarme con la paginación pero no entiendo cómo usarlo.

Comment: Muestra bien lo que llevas, de paso, lee esto: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination

Comment: mas o menos es este el caso para ti Eventos::chunck(100, function($eventos){
     foreach(){
     }
})

Answer (score 0):

Te propongo esta respuesta a tu pregunta

En el método que hayas declarado para tu controller, deberías tener el siguiente código

```
public function index()
    {
        $events = Eventos::paginate(10);
        return view('datos')->with('events', $events);
    }
```

Ahora dentro de la vista, hacemos lo siguiente

```
@foreach($events->chunk(100) as $fila)
        @foreach($fila as $item)
                {{ $item->columna_name1 }}
                 {{ $item->columna_name2 }}
        @endforeach
@endforeach

{{ $events->links() }}
```

> Como notas, dentro del método en el controller, invoco todos los
>   registros y accedo al método estático paginate, para indicarle cuantos
>   registros debe mostrarme por página
>
> El método chunk, lo uso dentro de la vista cuando accedo con el con el
>   objeto `$events` y le indico en cuantos bloques de resultados me va a
>   dividir la data completa
>
> Hago un doble foreach y muestro los datos.
>
> Para el caso de la paginación fuera de los 2 `foreach()` accediendo a
>   el con el objeto principal que mande a la vista es decir `$events`

Donde yo utilicé `columna_name1` y `columna_name2` tu debes sustituirlo por los nombres de tus columnas